# Average of a column with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the average of the time column and I am using few relationships to filter them, the problem is that some rows are being duplicated as they have two or more messages. Considering that I have the following tables and rows **(PostgreSQL 9.4)**.

```
|------------------------------|-----------|
| Times Table                              |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|
|   time   |   conversation    |   first   |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|
|   81250  |   1               |   true    |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|
|   63457  |   2               |   true    |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|
|   31592  |   3               |   true    |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|
|   33987  |   4               |   true    |
|----------|-------------------|-----------|

|------------------------|
| Conversations Table    |
|----------|-------------|
|    id    |   active    |
|----------|-------------|
|    1     |   true      |
|----------|-------------|
|    2     |   true      |
|----------|-------------|
|    3     |   true      |
|----------|-------------|
|    4     |   true      |
|----------|-------------|

|--------------------------------------------|
| Messages Table                             |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    id    |   conversation    |    agent    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    33    |   1               |    31181    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    37    |   2               |    17782    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    41    |   3               |    53132    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    44    |   3               |    53132    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
|    59    |   4               |    94282    |
|----------|-------------------|-------------|
```

And I'm trying to write a query that will return the average of time. So for the data above, the output from the query would look like:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
| Average Time                               |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 52571                                      |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

*81250 + 63457 + 31592 + 33987 = 210286 / 4 = 52571 (aprox.)*

This is my current query (something is wrong):

```
SELECT AVG("Times"."time") FROM "Times" AS "Average Time"
INNER JOIN "Conversations" ON "Conversations"."id" = "Times"."conversation" AND "Conversations"."active" = true
INNER JOIN "Messages" ON "Messages"."conversation" = "Conversations"."id" AND "Messages"."agent" IN ('31181', '17782', '53132', '94282')
WHERE "Times"."first" = true;
```

This is giving me the following output:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
| Average Time                               |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 48375                                      |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

*81250 + 63457 + 31592 + 31592 + 33987 = 210286 / 5 = 48375 (aprox.)*

I am trying to use distinct, groups and a few other aggregation functions but I fail. Here is a sqlfiddle with an example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5833fe/8

Comment: Do the duplicate values always match on `conversation` and `agent`? Or can you use `conversation` only?

Comment: The agent can be different but the conversation always matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested subquery to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT AVG(Times.time) FROM Times
WHERE Times.conversation IN (
    SELECT Conversations.id FROM Conversations 
    INNER JOIN Messages ON Messages.conversation = Conversations.id
      AND Messages.agent IN (31181, 17782, 53132, 94282)
    WHERE Conversations.active = true)
    AND Times.active = true;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5833f/5